# memory initialization with riscv32 ASM

Tags: c, fpga, inline-assembly, riscv32

I want to initialize memory block of riscv32 x'10000000 to x'10002000 with 0 to 2048 and variable "key" will take the value from address x'10000400 as the pass word. Because of optimization of assembler, use a pointer can't work, so I try to write with inline assembly. And while charge in card, no response when I tap the enter button. I suppose the program block in somewhere. The wrong part of code is shown as below.

```
    int key=0;

    asm volatile(
        "li t0, 0\n\t"
        "li t1, 0x10000000\n\t"
        "loop: \n\t"
        "sw t0, 0(t1)\n\t"
        "addi t0, t0, 1\n\t"
        "addi t1, t1, 4\n\t"
        "li t2, 0x800\n\t"
        "blt t0, t2, loop\n\t"
        );

    asm volatile(        
        "li t0, 0x10000400\n\t"
        "lw %[key], 0(t0)\n\t"
        : [key] "=r" (key)
    );
```

I have tried to correct my code. The new one is as below. I use a pointer to initialize the memory, but when I load the program in my card, it can't execute ether.

```
    unsigned int i;
    unsigned int *mem_ptr=(unsigned int *)0x10000000;
    for (i = 0; i < 0x800; i++) {
    asm volatile(
        "sw %[i], 0(%[mem_ptr])\n\t"
        : [mem_ptr] "+r" (mem_ptr)
        : [i] "r" (i)
        :);
        if (mem_ptr==0x10000400) {
            key=i;
        }
        mem_ptr=mem_ptr+4;
        }
```

Comment: Sounds like you want a `volatile uint32_t *`.  You don't need inline asm to do stuff to memory at an absolute address.  But if you were going to, an `asm` statement that uses registers without telling the compiler about it (clobber declarations) can't work safely either.  https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/ConvertBasicAsmToExtended  and other stuff in https://stackoverflow.com/tags/inline-assembly/info  Also, your [mcve] left out any details of what problem you had when running it.

Comment: As a side note, please **do not** insert a blank line after every line. It makes the code
much less readable and reduces the number of lines to be displayed at a time.

Comment: When I use **volatile uint32_t**, the compiler will automatically do the optimization and the program doesn't initialize the value in the address I want. So I try to write an asm code to force the compiler do not optimize @Peter Cordes

Comment: As a sidenote: You might have more people looking at the question if you gave it a better title. "issue during implementation" could be *any* question on this site. It also helps people find your question that have the same problem if you give it a more specific title.

Comment: `volatile` prevents compile-time constant-propagation.  If `volatile` didn't work, you used it wrong.  What did you see with a debugger when you single-stepped the asm generated by a compiler when you used `volatile`?  vs. in this case, when you single-step the compiler-generated asm from this source using inline `asm volatile`?

Comment: Your title edit didn't fix the problem @PeterKrebs pointed out.  You basically just added the tags to it, but haven't said anything about what kind of issue.  It could apply to every RISC-V inline asm question.

Comment: There you go, that's a better title.  The question itself is still a case of not using GNU C inline asm properly, not telling the compiler about registers you're modifying, like I mentioned in the first comment.  If there's any problem other than that, IDK, because that obvious problem needs to get fixed before it's worth looking for others.

Comment: `mem_ptr=mem_ptr+4` increases it by `4*sizeof(unsigned int)`.  Are you sure that's what you want?  Your asm loop was only increasing by one `uint32_t` at a time.

Comment: I think I understand, if I use "unsigned int", means each memory case is 32 bit not 8 bit, and this cause error@Peter Cordes